# How to count number of '\n' in QString qt c++

Tags: c++, string, qt

How to count number of '\n' in QString qt c++? or how can I convert QString to the format that shows '\n' to use string.count('\n) (QString does not show ones)?

```
QSize Delegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                         const QModelIndex &index) const {
...
QStyleOptionViewItem opt(option);
qDebug() << opt.text  //"""aaa
                      //aaa"""
qDebug() << opt.text.count('\n') //0'''
...
```

Comment: How did you get this `QString`? And what version of Qt you are using? I just used `string.count('\n')` in Qt 5.15 and it works.

Comment: Qt 6, getting a string this way: 
```QStyleOptionViewItem opt```, then ```opt.text```

Comment: Please, provide minimal reproducible example. I installed Qt 6 and `QString("foo\n bar\n foobar\n").count('\n')` works fine.

Comment: eddited the question

Comment: if you go to https://doc.qt.io/qt-{version}/qstring.html#count it says the same. Is it possible that your string has no new line in it?

Comment: `QStyleOptionViewItem::text` contains QString displayed by the view item.  It's quite possible that it doesn't contain `\n` unless placed them there explicitly. If text doesn't fit width-wise, what you see would be plain line-wrapping

Comment: got it, im using it to set the hight of a box containing the text and i want to shrink it to fit input text, any ideas to do it without counting ```\n```?

Comment: Which widget are you using? You can check [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/96392/qtextedit-minimal-height-but-expanding-problem/12) for `QTextEdit`. If I understood correctly what you want.